# Jquery if span[itemprop=employmentType] has = specific text/output

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement

I need help on how to find specific itemprop and if it has an specific output/text its should change other class/div css.

```
 $("span[itemprop='employmentType']").each(function(){
 if($(this).text()=='Third Party Job')
 {
   $('.wpjb-job-apply').css('display','none');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("span[itemprop='employmentType']").each(function(){
 if($(this).text()=='Third Party Jobs')
 {
   $(this).addClass("wpjb-job-apply");
 }
});
```

OR

```
 $("span[itemprop='employmentType']").each(function(){
 if($(this).text()=='Third Party Jobs')
 {
   $(this).css('display','none');
 }
});
```

CSS :

```
.wpjb-job-apply{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: if <span itemprop="employmentType">( has this text)Third Party Jobs</span> add display:none to class .wpjb-job-apply

Comment: $("span[itemprop='employmentType']").each(function(){
 if($(this).text()=='Third Party Job')
 {
   $('.wpjb-job-apply').css('display','none');
 }
});

Comment: There is already a div with class .wpjb-job-apply which is outside of the span itemprop div but if the itemprop has text Third Party Job it should update the .wpjb-job-apply to display:none sorry if am confusing thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
 $(function() {
    $('span[itemprop="employmentType"]').each(function(){
       $this = $(this);
       if($.trim($this.text() == "Third Party Job"){
          $this.addClass("wpjb-job-apply");
       }
    });
});
```